# yml mapping values are not allowed here (syntax)

Tags: yaml, markdown, mkdocs

I have removed half of what I wanted in this yaml file trying to find a way to get it to build my mkdocs test site and I have gotten down to one error.

```
'''
mkdocs.yml
doc/
Scaling-Issue.md
FreeSwitch.md
User-Sessions.md
nav:
-Common Issues:
 -Scaling Issue:'Scaling-Issue.md'
 -FreeSwitch:'FreeSwitch.md'
 -User Sessions:'User-Sessions.md'
'''
```

Error: 6:4 syntax error: mapping values are not allowed here

Comment: Are the entire contents of the code block above the contents of your file? If not, please edit your question so that that is the case.

Comment: Yea thats all thats left in my code block. I just wanted to get a basic version up and running to know I was using the right syntax and everything.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a lot of stuff in your configuration file which does not belong. Your file should look like this:

```
site_name: 'Your Site Name'
nav:
    - Common Issues:
        - Scaling Issue:'Scaling-Issue.md'
        - FreeSwitch:'FreeSwitch.md'
        - User Sessions:'User-Sessions.md'
```

First of all, the `site_name` option is required. Of course, you can change the actual name to whatever you want.

While `nav` is optional, it is recommended. I have cleaned up the indentation (four spaces is recommended rather than the one you were using). Also, you should have a space after each hyphen in your list items.

The other things do not go in the file. For example, the name of the file should not be included in the file. And I'm not sure where the three dots come from. Finally, the list of files is not something that goes in the file. I realize that all of those things may exist in documentation, but those are showing examples of what the file structure looks like, they are not things to add to the configuration file.

Comment: Alright ive been messing with this all day going off of some examples and Ill post the beginning and end of it as its too long to post but the middle of it is just fonts, and themes.
site_name: DirectCare_Documentation
site_url: https://pages.github.cerner.com/directcare/DC__Documentation
repo_name: 'GitHub'
repo_url: https://github.cerner.com/CB071663/DC__Documentation/blob/patch-8/docs
edit_uri: edit/master/docs/
strict: true

Comment: nav:
    - Home: 'index.md'
    - Common Issues:
        - Scaling Issue: 'Scaling-Issue.md'
        - FreeSwitch: 'FreeSwitch.md'
        - User Sessions: 'User-Sessions.md'

Comment: Error below:
C:\Users\cb071663>python -m mkdocs build
INFO    -  Cleaning site directory
INFO    -  Building documentation to directory: C:\Users\cb071663\site
WARNING -  A relative path to 'DC_Connect/Scaling-Issue.md' is included in the 'nav' configuration, which is not found in the documentation files
WARNING -  A relative path to 'DC_Connect/FreeSwitch.md' is included in the 'nav' configuration, which is not found in the documentation files
WARNING -  A relative path to 'DC_Connect/User-Sessions.md' is included in the 'nav' configuration, which is not found in the documentation files

Comment: Please edit your question and include the information there in a format we can read and make sense of.